# Receive Location Autohandling false email alerts

Tags: powershell, biztalk

```
$exceptionList = Get-Content C:\Users\Dipen\Desktop\Exception_List.txt

$ReceiveLocations = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter '(IsDisabled = True)' |
                    Where-Object { $exceptionList -notcontains $_.Name }

# Exit the script if there are no disabled receive locations
if ($ReceiveLocations.Count -eq 0)
{
    exit
}
```

Example:

[image: Disabled_RLs]

and

[image: Exception_List]

```
$mailBodyPT = ""

$mailTextReportPT = "There are: "
[STRING]$Subject = $SubjectPrefix + $BizTalkGroup
$mailTextReportPT += "in the BizTalk group: " + $BizTalkGroup + "." 

#Send mail
foreach ($to in $EmailTo) 
{
    $Body = $HTMLmessage
    #$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($PSEmailServer) 
    $message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $Subject, $Body)
    $message.IsBodyHtml = $true;
    $SMTPClient.Send($message)
}
```

Question: when all RLs have the status "disabled" and all of these RLs are included in the exception list the value of the variable `$ReceiveLocations` should be false and I need to stop further processing in my script. (do nothing if all RLs are found in exception list, just exit)

But I'm still getting false email alerts. How can we set logic for not getting email alerts if there were no extra RLs found in `$ReceiveLocations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the variable `$ReceiveLocations` is `$null` when your `Get-WmiObject` statement doesn't return results. `$null` doesn't have a property `Count`, hence the check `$ReceiveLocations.Count -eq 0` fails and your script doesn't terminate before sending an e-mail.

You can avoid this issue in a number of ways, e.g. by putting `$ReceiveLocations` in the [array subexpression operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators):

```
if (@($ReceiveLocations).Count -eq 0) {
    exit
}
```

or you could use the way PowerShell interprets [values in boolean expressions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/) (non-empty arrays become `$true`, `$null` becomes `$false`):

```
if (-not $ReceiveLocations) {
    exit
}
```

Comment: ++, but it's worth noting that the unified handling of scalars and collections introduced in PSv3 (methinks) _does_ allow using `.Count` on a null-valued expression and sensibly returns `0`: `$null.Count -eq 0` returns `$true` in PSv3+, whereas it returns `$false` in PSv2-.

Comment: I thought it didn't, but I just verified and you're right. I'd probably still prefer not to rely on it, though, if only for compatibility reasons.